# MVC binding model to dropdownlist in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I am fairly new to MVC and am trying to get away form using WebForms, but some things are confusing me as to what I need to get certain things done.

In my view "/areas/admin/cars/form.cshtml" I want to use **@Html.Dropdownfor**, passing in a list of my car manufacturers which is defined by the CarManufacturer.cs model. How do I do this please?

*I am using nhibernate - not sure if that makes any different...*

Model;

```
public class CarManufacturer
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        //***do i need the below line?***
        public SelectList CarManufacturerList { get; set; }  
    }

    public class CarManufacturerMap : ClassMapping<CarManufacturer>
    {
        public CarManufacturerMap()
        {
            Table("CarManufacturers");
            Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
            Property(x => x.Manufacturer, x => x.NotNullable(true));
        }
    }
```

The Controller calling the form is carController.cs

```
    public ActionResult New()
            {
                //re-susing views for add and edit
                return View("Form", new CarsForm
                {
                    IsNew = true,
                });
            }

            public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                var car = Database.Session.Load<Car>(id);
                if (car == null)
                    return HttpNotFound();

                return View("Form", new CarsForm
                {
                    ...do stuff here to populate form fields!...
                });
            }
```

ViewModel;

```
public class CarsForm
    {
        //do I need the below line?
        public IList<CarManufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

        public bool IsNew { get; set; }//whether add or edit action to be used
        public int? CarId { get; set; }
...more fields
}
```

Many thanks for patience and help with a new MVC'er!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually add dropdownlist data to viewbag. You can remove the lists from your viewmodel and entity class.

your controller would look like this.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    ViewBag.Manufacturers = new SelectList(
        Database.Session.Load<Manufacturer>(), 
        "Manufacturer", 
        "Manufacturer");
    return View("Form", new CarsForm
    {
        IsNew = true,
    });
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var car = Database.Session.Load<Car>(id);
    if (car == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    ViewBag.Manufacturers = new SelectList(
        Database.Session.Load<Manufacturer>(), 
        "Manufacturer", 
        "Manufacturer", 
        car.Manufacturer); //sets the initial value
    return View("Form", new CarsForm
    {
        ...do stuff here to populate form fields!...
    });
}
```

Then in your view you just add your `@Html.DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manufacturer, (SelectList)ViewBag.Manufacturers)
```

Comment: Ahhh, now I see how the viewbag method works, and I think I prefer it to passing a model into the DDL which is where I was having issues! :) THanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is one approach, and personally my preferred approach in smaller projects, but there are a few ways to skin this particular cat.

Hopefully you will have noticed that `Html.DropDownListFor` takes a `List<SelectListItem>` so you can go ahead and declare one in your view model, but you'll also need the `Id` of the particular manufacturer selected:

```
public class CarsForm
{
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Manufacturers { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

As a side note, the naming convention for view models would be `CreateCarViewModel` for example.

In your `New` method, you will need to instantiate `Manufacturers` from your database, usually it will be something like this:

```
viewModel.Manufacturers = (from m in dbContext.Manufacturers
                          orderby m.Name
                          select new SelectLisItem { Text = m.Name, Value = m.Id.ToString() }).ToList()
```

Now, in your `View` you can do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Manufacturers, Model.ManufacturerId, "Please select")
```

Comment: you'll probably get an error using m.Id.ToString() if you're selecting directly from the dbcontext

Comment: @user1221684 I'm not sure that's the case, but easily remedied with a `ToList()` nonetheless

Comment: you can also use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)m.Id)`

Comment: yeah so does `EntityFunctions.AddDays(a.Date, 3)` as opposed to `a.Data.AddDays(3)` but at least you don't get errors and don't have to do `(from m in db).ToList().Select(func).ToList()`.. Plus for some reason OP has `string Manufacturer` instead of `int ManufacturerId` so your `Value` would just `m.Name` also